# How do i set the ColorIndex from a characters object to the ColorIndex from another?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an characters object:

```
Sheets("MySheet").cells(1, 1).Characters(startInt, 1)
```

and I want to set the color of this one character to

```
Sheets("MySheet").cells(2, 2).Characters(startInt, 1).Font.Color
```

But when I do

```
Sheets("MySheet").cells(1, 1).Characters(startInt, 1).Font.Color = Sheets("MySheet").cells(2, 2).Characters(startInt, 1).Font.Color
```

I get an "incompatible types" error. Same error when using ColorIndex instead of Color. How do I set the color of an font object to the color of another?

Comment: Try with `.Font.Color` instead of `.Color`

Comment: @Teamothy i did that, just typed wrong in the question. sorry

Comment: Works fine for me.  Is there something else in the rest of your code which is causing the problem? Try (eg) `Debug.Print Sheets("MySheet").cells(2, 2).Characters(startInt, 1).Font.Color` - what do you get?

Comment: @Luca100 Perhaps try copy/paste from the code you have written, rather than typing it out again?  That would help us identify if you have any typos in your code that are causing the issues.

Comment: Yes I have heard about this error many times earlier as well but have never been able to reproduce it. Possible to see your workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Following code is worked for me in my recent project.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(2, 1).Characters(Start:=5, Length:=1).Font.Color = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=5, Length:=1).Font.Color
```

Note that start point is inclusive. When you write 5, it will take the fifth character in the string. Also I added `Thisworkbook` because there might different opened excels at the same time. Using worksheets alone always go to active workbook and it might be a different excel.